# Spring boot + jpa, many to many association through form submission

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

hi everyone i just started to learn spring boot and was wondering how can i save objects with many to many relationship through form submission?

say we have two entities of book and publisher

```
@Entity
public class Book{
private long id;
private String name;
private List<Publisher> publishers;

public Book() {

}

public Book(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Book(String name, Set<Publisher> publishers){
    this.name = name;
    this.publishers = publishers;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "book_publisher", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
public List<Publisher> getPublishers() {
    return publishers;
}

public void setPublishers(List<Publisher> publishers) {
    this.publishers = publishers;
  }
}

@Entity
public class Publisher {
private Long id;
private String name;
private List<Book> books;

public Publisher(){

}

public Publisher(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public Publisher(String name, List<Book> books){
    this.name = name;
    this.books = books;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "publishers")
public List<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
    this.books = books;
}
}
```

and then we have a book repository

```
public interface BookRepository extends CRUDRepository<Book, Long>{
}
```

how would crud methods look like in bookcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

the real question is the "connection table" has additional data , for example date the publishing of the book by the publisher , ISBN of the book from that publisher and so on ... 
if the answer is yes then it requires another form , and that solves your issue , if not , you receive from the form list of publishers of the book you enter and add them separately to the connection table and the book to the book table through the book repository ... 
from my point of view the design of the database is lacking info. 
when you will answer to that question, ill try to help you to do it the spring way ... 
currenly from db point of view to make such connection between objects you need existing objects . and the first stage fromwise is form for `Publisher` and form for `Book`. 
many to many is known to be a headache . 
i would suggest to add `JPA` tag to the question, and remove the `spring-data` .

Comment: thank you so much for your answer.@NiNiCkNaMe. the answer to the question "does connection table has additional data" is no. so i need to have a form for publisher and then in book form i should have list of publishers?